# Wizard in Android app - use system or separate back button?

Tags: mobile, android, back-button

A mobile app wizard, when finished have an additional function (if used - screen isn't changed).

Does it should have:
1. A separate "Back" (to main screen) button or
2. it's enough allowing the user use system's built-in "back"?

[image]

Comment: Can you specify the actions and goal of the app and this segment of the app?

Comment: A user: 1. Fills a form -- 2. Submits it -- 3. Optionally prints it (1 or more times) -- 4. Goes back to main menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Back" means that you go back to the previous screen. The android back button also serves the same principle.

Since your app's back button would bring the user back to the home screen rather than back to the previous screen, I'd call the button differently. Maybe "Done" or "Home".

Comment: @UXLV No problem! Does it fully answer your question?

Comment: My question is about choosing between option 1 and 2, is there should be a "finish" button or not? As i understood you choose option 1.

Comment: Exactly, a finish button will do the trick! :-)